# Different PCIe spec on server compared to desktop?

Tags: server, pcie, network-adapter

Is there a different PCIe spec for server motherboards compared to desktops?

I recently purchased a [PCIe gigabit networking card](https://www.ebay.com/itm/324314108021?mkevt=1&mkpid=0&emsid=e11051.m43.l1123&mkcid=7&ch=osgood&euid=00c40da9cd4442baac7e48c27a2ca312&bu=43499568270&osub=-1%7E1&crd=20230926115912&segname=11051) (Cisoc Dual Port 1GB Rj-45 Network Ethernet Server Card Broadcom NetXtreme, model number: 49Y7947). I tried it in 3 different desktop computers that all have PCIe 16x lanes, but the card appears to have no power even when the desktop starts up fine. I tried linux, windows. The card appears totally dead, no blinking lights on the card, doesn't show up in the bios, etc.

When I reached out to the seller, they said

> Servers possess PCIe ports similar to desktop computers, but their hardware and software are engineered and configured differently from those of desktops. The hardware and software on desktop systems are not compatible with this adapter, and as a result, it will not be detected. This adapter is specifically designed for use with servers and is not intended for desktop use.

Is this true? I was under the impression that there is only really *one* PCIe specification across all modern hardware, so it seems odd that there would be a "Server" PCIe spec and a "Non-server" PCIe spec but both called PCIe.

Comment: No, there are not different PCIe specs for servers and desktops. The explanation from the seller was saying that the adapter is designed for specific servers. Lots of enterprise hardware is designed to only work in official motherboards so that they can ensure customers continue buying their components and customer support.